# Why is my SSRS report not appearing in my browser?

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm trying to view my SSRS report in a browser.  According to [this MSDN page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255286%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), I should see a page that looks like this:

[image]

When I load that page on the computer hosting my SSRS report, I get no results at all.  My browser looks like:

[image]

I am able to preview my report in Visual Studio Business Intelligence Development Studio and the report looks exactly like I'd expect.  I can also export the report to a PDF file and it looks fine.  What could I be doing wrong with regards to viewing my report in a browser.

Comment: Have you actually deployed the report to your local Report Server? You say you're just previewing through BIDS, which is rendering it in BIDS, not the Report Server. Right now your local Report Server has nothing to display; either you don't have the specific rights or there are simply no items to display.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that.  I had to set the TargetServerURL (RightClick on the project name in the Solution Explorer and then enter http://localhost/ReportServer and click OK).  Then I had to deploy the project (Menu > Build > Deploy Project).  Now I can load the report in a browser by going to http://localhost/ReportServer.  Thanks.

Comment: OK, great, I've added as an answer now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you haven't actually deployed the report to your local Report Server.

You say you're just previewing through BIDS, which is rendering it in BIDS, not the Report Server itself.

Right now your local Report Server has nothing to display; either you don't have the specific rights or there are simply no items to display.

You need to deploy either the individual report or the project to the Report Server.